# React, How to detect a specific character is typed inside a form field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have an "input field" component. I need to show an alert, if the "#" character is typed inside the input field. Is there any way, we can determine the character is typed.

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    handleKeyPress(e) {
        // show an alert if "#" character is pressed
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <input onChange={this.handleKeyPress}>
        )
    }
}
```

**Edit**

I wanted to show the alert just after the user typed a "#" character. afterward he can continue typing any character without an alert prompting. If the user type another "#" inside the input field, the alert should be appeared again.

Any idea  is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `event.target.value` to get the value and to get the latest character use `e.target.value[e.target.value.length - 1]` and check if has `#`.

Hope this helps!

```js
class DayView extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    handleKeyPress(e) {
      if( e.target.value[e.target.value.length - 1] === '#' )
        setTimeout(()=> alert('Got #'), 200)
        // show an alert if "#" character is pressed
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <input onChange={this.handleKeyPress}/>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<DayView/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting. Your answer is really helpful. I have add some more description on the question. Your answering is appreciated

Comment: @ErangaKapukotuwa Updated the answer.

Comment: You can adjust the delay time as you want

Comment: Working. Thank you @Pranesh

Comment: I don't knew that, an approval already made is removing by adding an another approval. the second answer is also halfway correct. That's why I added my "approval" into it. Anyway I corrected it.

Comment: @ErangaKapukotuwa That's not an issue. That code won't work as per your requirement. You wanted 'to show the alert just after the user typed a "#" character' ryt? That will show the alert before # is displayed in the input box.

Answer (score 2):

```
export default class DayView extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: ''
    };

    // Bind `this`
    this.handleKeyPress = this.handleKeyPress.bind(this);
  }

  handleKeyPress(e) {
    // Get input value
    var value = e.target.value;
    // User has already typed a #
    var hasSymbol = !!value.substring(0, value.length - 1).match(/\#/);

    // Check if last character is a #
    if (value[value.length - 2] === '#') {
      alert('There is a # symbol');
    }

    // Check if this last character is a #
    // and the value already has one
    if (hasSymbol && value[value.length - 1] === '#') {
      alert('There is an other # symbol');
    }

    // Set state
    this.setState({ value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input onChange={this.handleKeyPress} value={this.state.value}>
    )
  }
}
```

- [Form in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html)
- [React and ES6, Binding to methods of React class](http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/08/16/react-and-es6-part3.html)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. And it really helpful. I wanted to show the alert just after the user typed a "#" character. afterward he can continue typing any character without an alert prompting. If the user type another "#" inside the input field, the alert should be appeared again.

Answer (score 1):

`keyUp` is suitable in this context more than `keyPress` & `change`;

Hope this helps!

```js
class DayView extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        this.handleKeyUp= this.handleKeyUp.bind(this);
    }

    handleKeyUp(e) {
     
       this.refs.atom.value.endsWith('#')  && setTimeout(()=> alert('Got #'), 200) // show an alert if "#" character is pressed
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <input ref="atom" onKeyUp={this.handleKeyUp}/>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<DayView/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```